# Write-Output variable results to a new .parquet OR .csv file into Azure Storage Account using Azure Powershell Runbook

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-runbook

Good Day,

I've the following MDXQuery returning 2 columns

```
SELECT[TableID], [Name] FROM $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS
```

[image]

The idea is to use an Azure Powershell runbook to create either a csv or parque file and save it to a specific container and folder. The powershell code must do the bellow steps:

1-Execute the DMX Query to get the data

2-Parse the results as XML to a variable called $Results

3-Write-Output the results from variable $Results and create either a csv or .parquet file

4-Make sure the file goes into a specific Azure storage Account

I cannot accomplish the last 2 steps as I do not know how , I was thinking on using  Set-AzStorageBlobContent but based on the Microsoftdetails this is more to Uploads a local file to an Azure Storage blob and not to use the result of an XML variable to create the file from scratch.

This is my script in the Azure runbook

```
Param
(
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $Query,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $OperationType,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $ServerName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $DatabaseName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $SecretName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $ResourceGroupName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $StorageAccountName

)

$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $SecretName

$Results = [XML] (Invoke-ASCmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $cred -Query $Query)

Write-Output  $Results.return.root.row

# Connect using a Managed Service Identity
try {
        $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
    }
catch{
        Write-Output "There is no system-assigned user identity. Aborting."; 
        exit
    }

Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName
```

The output results are 3 columns  , unless the MDX query adds more but I need to use this to create the file with the same amount of columns and data. File needs to be created in the Azure storage account being specified on the powershell code

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to security I cannot use Storage Key. I must use Manage Identity. I've removed some variables that were not needed and added additional ones to create a second file with different data.

```
    Param
(
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $ServerName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $DatabaseName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $SecretName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $StorageAccountName,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $Query,
  [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
  [String] $Query2

)

$cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name $SecretName

$Results = [XML] (Invoke-ASCmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $cred -Query $Query)
$report = Write-Output  $Results.return.root.row
$report | Export-CSV -Encoding ASCII ($env:TEMP+"AS_PartitionsData.csv") -Notype -Delimiter "`t" | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} 

$Results2 = [XML] (Invoke-ASCmd -Server $ServerName -Database $DatabaseName -Credential $cred -Query $Query2)
$report2 = Write-Output  $Results2.return.root.row
$report2 | Export-CSV -Encoding ASCII ($env:TEMP2+"AS_TableNamesData.csv") -Notype -Delimiter "`t" | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} 


# Connect using a Managed Service Identity
try {
        $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context
    }
catch{
        Write-Output "There is no system-assigned user identity. Aborting."; 
        exit
    }

$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName

Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "mapping" -File ($env:TEMP+"AS_PartitionsData.csv") -Blob "AS_PartitionsData.csv" -Force 
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "mapping" -File ($env:TEMP2+"AS_TableNamesData.csv") -Blob "AS_TableNamesData.csv" -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot accomplish the last 2 steps as I do not know how

I have reproduce in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-9.6.0) and [Microsoft-Documnet2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-9.6.0):

Here $r contains a table.

```
$s = "rithwik"
$c = "rithwik"
$k = "rCQR+OahV3cWz8sPK5GLS0hT/C+AStNYbM6Q=="
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $s -StorageAccountKey $k

$r=Get-Module
$r | Export-csv -Path emo.csv -NoTypeInformation
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "emo.csv" -Container $c -Blob "emo.csv" -Context $Context
```

[image]

Here $s is storage account name

$c is container name

$k is  storage account key

Output:

[image]

File got exported to Storage account as csv file.

[image]

Contents:

[image]

By following above code/process you can set the content as csv and then export it to specific storage account.

Comment: The Export-csv  & Set-AzStorageBlobContentwas definetly was what I needed but I've done a work-around to actually display the $Results variable data into the new csv file. I ended up creating 2 new csv files because I have 2 different DMX Queries

Comment: I'll update the code on my quesiton using part of the logic behind your code Rith